# How does table in Dynamic Programming works?

Tags: c++, string

I have been studying dynamic programming now a days and i came across a code on a website.
The question says  write a function that checks whether C is an interleaving of A and B. C is said to be interleaving A and B, if it contains all characters of A and B and order of all characters in individual strings is preserved.What i don't understand is how values get filled in the 2-D matrix ?

Help needed :)
Here is the link 
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-whether-a-given-string-is-an-interleaving-of-two-other-given-strings-set-2/

```
// an interleaving of A and B, otherwise false.
bool isInterleaved(char* A, char* B, char* C)
{
  // Find lengths of the two strings
  int M = strlen(A), N = strlen(B);

  // Let us create a 2D table to store solutions of
  // subproblems.  C[i][j] will be true if C[0..i+j-1]
  // is an interleaving of A[0..i-1] and B[0..j-1].
  bool IL[M + 1][N + 1];

  memset(IL, 0, sizeof(IL)); // Initialize all values as false.

  // C can be an interleaving of A and B only of sum
  // of lengths of A & B is equal to length of C.
  if ((M + N) != strlen(C))
    return false;

  // Process all characters of A and B
  for (int i = 0; i <= M; ++i)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j <= N; ++j)
    {
      // two empty strings have an empty string
      // as interleaving
      if (i == 0 && j == 0)
        IL[i][j] = true;

      // A is empty
      else if (i == 0 && B[j - 1] == C[j - 1])
        IL[i][j] = IL[i][j - 1];

      // B is empty
      else if (j == 0 && A[i - 1] == C[i - 1])
        IL[i][j] = IL[i - 1][j];

      // Current character of C matches with current character of A,
      // but doesn't match with current character of B
      else if (A[i - 1] == C[i + j - 1] && B[j - 1] != C[i + j - 1])
        IL[i][j] = IL[i - 1][j];

      // Current character of C matches with current character of B,
      // but doesn't match with current character of A
      else if (A[i - 1] != C[i + j - 1] && B[j - 1] == C[i + j - 1])
        IL[i][j] = IL[i][j - 1];

      // Current character of C matches with that of both A and B
      else if (A[i - 1] == C[i + j - 1] && B[j - 1] == C[i + j - 1])
        IL[i][j] = (IL[i - 1][j] || IL[i][j - 1]);
    }
  }

  return IL[M][N];
}

void test(char *A, char *B, char *C)
{
  if (isInterleaved(A, B, C))
    cout << C << " is interleaved of " << A << " and " << B << endl;
  else
    cout << C << " is not interleaved of " << A << " and " << B << endl;
}

// Driver program to test above functions
int main()
{
  test("XXY", "XXZ", "XXZXXXY");
}
```

Comment: A link to the website would help to set the context for your question.

Comment: yes sure! i have edited the question check

Answer (score 2):

[Dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) re-uses the results of sub-problems to solve the problem. The sub-problems are smaller versions of the problem. A table is often used to store the sub-problem results.

The indices of the table are application specific; in this case, they are described in the comments:

```
// Let us create a 2D table to store solutions of
// subproblems.  IL[i][j] will be true if C[0..i+j-1]
// is an interleaving of A[0..i-1] and B[0..j-1].
```

(I fixed a mistake, `C[i][j]` should be `IL[i][j]` in the original source).

The sub-problems determine whether substrings of `A` and `B` are interleavings of substrings of C. The indices into the IL array determine the length of the substrings of `A` and `B` (the length of the third substring is implied from the lengths of the other two).

For example:

- `IL[0][0]` is `true`, since "" (empty string) and "" interleave to form "".
- `IL[0][*]` is also `true`, since "" and `WHATEVER` interleave to form `WHATEVER` (here, `*` means "anything").
- `IL[*][0]` is also `true`, for similar reasons to the above.
- `IL[i][j]` is calculated by comparing the current character in `C` to the current characters in `A` and `B` (look at the source code to determine what I mean by "current")

  - If it matches neither, then you know that `C` is **not** an interleaving, since it contains an unexpected character. Therefore, `IL[i][j] = false`.
  - If it matches `A`, then you also need to check that the previous characters interleave correctly as well. Here's where the dynamic programming part comes in -- you don't need to actually look at all those characters to check them, since you've already done that in previous iterations. The result of the check (which is also the final result you should return) is stored inside the `IL` table, more specifically, at `IL[i-1][j]`.  Therefore, `IL[i][j] = IL[i-1][j]`.
  - If it matches `B`, then do the same as above, except look at `IL[i][j-1]`.

If you have trouble understanding the dynamic programming solution, I recommend that you work manually through the recursive solution on the site. Eventually, you will realize that you're repeating many comparisons. You can avoid this repetition by storing the comparison result the first time you have to make it, and then re-using that result on subsequent occasions.